# Data not getting inserted into database with foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have built a multidimensional array that contains the Table name, Column name and values to be inserted. I convert this array into an `INSERT` command and then execute it. Everything has been working as intended until I tried inserting into the same table twice. I have a parent table `company`. All of the other 19 tables in the database contain a column named `CompanyID` which is a foreign key that references the `CompanyID` column in the `company` table. What I need to do is be able to insert into one of the child tables twice for an additional address or contact people for that company. For some reason if I duplicate the array so that it should add into a certain table twice it will only insert once. No errors are thrown either. Can someone help me sort this out.

Here is the array:

```
$surveyResults = array(
                    'additionallocations' => array(
                            'CompanyID' => $CompanyID,
                            'Address' => $Address,
                            'City' => $City,
                            'State' => $State,
                            'Zip' => $Zip,
                            'Country' => $Country,
                        ),
                    'sales' => array(
                        'CompanyID' => $CompanyID,
                        'FirstName' => $FirstName,
                        'LastName' => $LastName,
                        'Email' => $Email,
                        'Phone' => $Phone
                        ),
                    'owner' => array(
                        'CompanyID' => $CompanyID,
                        'FirstName' => $FirstName,
                        'LastName' => $LastName,
                        'Email' => $Email,
                        'Phone' => $Phone
                        ),
                    'decisionmaker' => array(
                        'CompanyID' => $CompanyID,
                        'FirstName' => $FirstName,
                        'LastName' => $LastName,
                        'Email' => $Email,
                        'Phone' => $Phone
                        ),
                    'decisionmaker' => array(
                        'CompanyID' => $CompanyID,
                        'FirstName' => $FirstName,
                        'LastName' => $LastName,
                        'Email' => $Email,
                        'Phone' => $Phone
                        )
                    );
```

Notice `decisionmaker` is listed twice. This should insert into the database identical information but it only inserts once. I have even tried hard coding the last `decisionmaker` array values so they are all different besides the `CompanyID` and it still will not insert.

Below is how I am creating the SQL statement and executing it.

```
foreach($surveyResults as $key => $table){
                $sql1 = null;
        $keys = array_keys($table);
            $values = null;
            $x = 1;

            foreach($table as $row => $value) {
                $values .= "'$value'";
                if($x < count($keys)) {
                    $values .= ', ';
                }
                $x++;
            }

        $sql1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO {$key} (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values});");
        $sql1->execute();

        echo $CompanyID;
        echo "Successful  <br/>";
    }
```

Table creation query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `decisionmaker` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CompanyID` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `CompanyID` (`CompanyID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=24 ;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `decisionmaker`
--
ALTER TABLE `decisionmaker`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `DecisionMaker_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CompanyID`) REFERENCES `company` (`CompanyID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

This is the table dump for company:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `company` (
  `CompanyID` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `State` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Zip` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Website` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `NOL` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`CompanyID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=35 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is rather simple

$surveyResults has the same key for decisionmaker.

If you `print_r($surveyResults);` before your `foreach` for inserting data into your database, you  will realise that there is not two `decisionmaker` keys, but only one.

This is because an array can not contain the same key twice. For example

```
    $array = array( 'key' => 'for', 'key' => 'example' );
    print_r($array);
```

will only output

```
Array (
    [key] => example
)
```

A simple way to fix this:

1. on the second `decisionmaker` inside `surveyResults`, change the key to `decisionmaker2`
2. before `foreach($table as $row => $value) {` add the following code:

   ```
   if ($key == 'decisionmaker2')
         $key = 'decisionmaker';
   ```

That should resolve the issue that you are seeing :)

Comment: Simply frustrating :)

Comment: Thanks a lot I would give you a high five right now if I could

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the create statement for this table? FOREIGN KEYS require you to specify how to handle duplicates.

Comment: I use phpmyadmin and when I use the insert button there the INSERT query is identical to what I am giving it with my generated query

Comment: you did! Have you tried this outside of PHP directly into MySQL work bench or something similar? I don't see anything wrong with what you're doing. I will say that I don't see you scrubbing the input data from your survey and that's a big red flag. Hopefully you are, but that could lead to sql injection attacks if not. Be sure that you use real_escape_string on all of your inputs to be sure they are safe for insertion. Try this outside of php and see if it works... I'll try to import as well but im guessing this is php issue.

Comment: I have not implemented cleaning the data yet it is something that I will do once I get the database working properly I have a lot of work to do yet.

Comment: remove the foriegn key constraint, try the same test. Make sure the foreign key is the issue.

Comment: I removed the foreign key and it still does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code and just check how many times insert is being done.

And also set error mode on in your php settings so that you can see the error message.

After doing reply with your result.

```
foreach($surveyResults as $key => $table){
                $sql1 = null;
        $keys = array_keys($table);
            $values = null;
            $x = 1;

            foreach($table as $row => $value) {
                $values .= "'$value'";
                if($x < count($keys)) {
                    $values .= ', ';
                }
                $x++;
            }

        $sql1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO {$key} (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values});");
        if($sql1->execute())//changed code
          echo $CompanyID;

        echo "Successful  <br/>";
    }
```

Comment: I am not getting any errors and it executes 5 times

Comment: technically 4 because I have the initial insert for the new company

Comment: is your error and warning mode is set to on in php.ini

Comment: I added `ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);` at the top of the file

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your database. Problem may be with your query.

Comment: If I copy and paste the output of the php generated query into the phpmyadmin console it adds it just fine. I am stumped on this one for sure. If I add `deciscionmaker` 10 times and change the values of the very last one, only the last one gets inserted.

Comment: Its the same for all tables